# android split action bar rounded corner at bottom

Tags: android-actionbar, android

I need some help with Android UI design, I need to make rounded corner for the split action bar (that is the bottom part of an action bar).

Basically I can make rounded corners for top action bar but I have no clue how to do it for the bottom one.

Thanks!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you or not but it's working great for me, here is style file

```
    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Misschef" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_border</item>


    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_misschef</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_misschef</item> //bottom actionbar
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Misschef</item>
    </style>
```

be sure to use android:backgroundSplit instead of backgroundSplit in v14.

also [here](https://krishnalalstha.wordpress.com/tag/rounded-edge-actionbar/) is a quide for top actionbar, you can use it for bottom,to do so just change

```
android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
android:topRightRadius="4dp"
```

to

```
android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
android:topRightRadius="0dp"
```

let me now if this works.